# how to get multiple data value of the column in database?

Tags: php, mysql

Now I try to make new code with reference from Swellar. but i dont know why. that code wont work at all.
it wont showing the data. just show a blank page

this the code

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","silo");
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM temp5";
$rResult = $db->query($sQuery);

$aResult = array();
while($aRow = mysqli_fetch_array($rResult)){
   $aResult[] = $aRow;
}

// explode each row and store in a new array
 $aResultArrays = array();
 foreach ($aResult as $row){           
     $aResultArrays[$row['no']] = explode(',',$row['nama']);
 }
```

i have a problem to calling multiple data from database column. 
i want to call that into separate value.
[image]

at the circle i made. i want call it into a table but i must separate them first. the table i want to create like this

just example:

```
|Nurudin |09-07-2017|;
|Nur Chotib| 09-07-2017|;
|Heri Prasetyo| 09-07-2017|;
|Moch Ali Imron| 09-07-2017;
```

i hope someone can give me an example of the code for me.

Comment: What have you tried? Use explode() and foreach()!

Comment: You can use `explode` to get different value. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). And please show your code if you have tried.

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: get your data from table, then use php "explode()" and explode it based on comma(,) .you will get an array from which you can access your required data

Comment: Don't mix mysql_ and mysqli_ - it won't work. In fact don't use mysql_ at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this one:

```
$char='|';
foreach ($aResult as $row){           
     $aResultArrays[$row['no']] = $char.implode('|',explode(',',$row['nama'])).$char;
}
```

Comment: This is what you want? @Minervaz Mine

Comment: yeah like that. i have modified that into php code.
can you check it for me? why that code cant running well?

Answer (score 1):

Using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$names = explode(",",$retrievedNames);
foreach($names as $name)
{
    echo '|'.$name.'|'.$retrievedDate.'|';
}
```

Comment: where i must place explode in my script above?

Comment: I'm not really a user of `mysqli`, but use this after getting the data in the `nama` column

Answer (score 0):

While answers have been given, there shouldn't have been this problem in the first place since having multiple values in the same column is against [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), even 1NF.

Instead create a new table for all of your values in "Nama" and another one to map this table's ID with the new one's.

Example [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/Onetablewithtwoforeignkeys.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your first answer, but this should probably be a comment instead.

Comment: Looks like I need 50 reputation to comment